# Adjust horizontal distance in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, appendices

The horizontal distance between the dot after Appendix A and the section title Data Sources is not the same as the horizontal distance between the dot after 1 and the section title Data Sources in the table of contents. Is there a way to adjust this distance only for Appendix A, so that both distances are equal?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,DIV=12,BCOR=0mm,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%appendix
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\appendices}{\quad}{. }{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Data Sources}

\begin{appendices}

    \section{Data Sources}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure that the `appendix` package and the KOMA classes are compatible

Comment: What package would you recommend for KOMA classes?

Comment: I am no KOMA user, but I am pretty sure you can achieve the appendix look and layout you like with KOMA itself without using `appendix`. Or drop KOMA and use a standard class.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the number of a section entry in ToC is printed in a box of width 1.5em. So you could use a box of the same width for the appendix number in ToC:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,DIV=12,BCOR=0mm,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}% <- added

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\appendix
  {%
    \xpretocmd\sectionformat{\appendixname\enskip}{}{\PatchFailed}%
    \xpatchcmd{\addsectiontocentry}
      {\addtocentrydefault{section}{#1}{#2}}
      {%
        \ifstr{#1}{}
          {\addtocentrydefault{section}{}{#2}}
          {\addtocentrydefault{section}{}{\appendixname\ \makebox[1.5em][l]{#1\autodot}#2}}%
      }{}{\PatchFailed}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Data Sources}
%\setcounter{section}{9}
%\section{Other section}
\appendix
\section{Data Sources}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But note that the sep between the number and the text in ToC will also be smaller if there are sections with two digit numbers. If the should also have the same sep you could use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,DIV=12,BCOR=0mm,numbers=endperiod]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}% <- added

\renewcommand*\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}
  {\addtocentrydefault{section}{}{#2}}
  {\addtocentrydefault{section}{}{#1\autodot\enskip#2}}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\appendix
  {%
    \xpretocmd\sectionformat{\appendixname\enskip}{}{\PatchFailed}%
    \xpatchcmd{\addsectiontocentry}{#1\autodot}{\appendixname~#1\autodot}{}{\PatchFailed}%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Data Sources}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{Other section}
\appendix
\section{Data Sources}
\end{document}
```

[image]